# Unused switch ports in Fabric (brocade)

Tags: storage, storage-area-network, fabric, brocade

I am very new to storage but we are having trouble with performance on our SAN. While troubleshooting I found that one of our switches in the fabric (1 HP C7000 with 2 flexbric interfaces connected to 2 SAN Switches connected to 2 HP 3Par SAN nodes) had pretty much no traffic.

I was wondering if that kind of situation was "expected" (maybe it's using 1 switch as primary and the second as failover) or if it could indicate some problem.

When running a single "porterrshow" on the Brocades, or "portperfshow", I can see a lot of stats on Fabric_A but almost nothing on Fabric_B.

Is it normal to have traffic on just one interface, and not load balanced across interfaces?

Let me know if you need any details on the setup.

Comment: You need to configure the hosts to use paths on both fabrics.

Comment: thank you Basil, so the problem might be on the hosts side ? i will check there (as we have the exact same setup on another site and it works perfectly fine there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we indeed had a wrong storage policy configured on the VMware/ESX side.
We reconfigured it from MRU to RR (round robin) and can now see all paths being used and traffic on every switch